# Multiple S3 Inputs into Glue Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-data-pipeline

I have 3 separate data sources (files) in 3 separate S3 buckets. The schema in these 3 sources are different from one another but the timestamp is the same (hourly in epoch).

Previously, I used Glue to read from 1 bucket and apply transformations to the files in that bucket and write to a resulting bucket.

With the 3 data sources, can I still read them from 3 different buckets and somehow join them on the epoch timestamp and then spit out the unified datasource (combination of all 3) .. I guess Glue will have to do row level JOINS in this case.

The blog posts about Glue I have found on the web so far only talk about single source input and transformations.

If this is not possible the way I am asking it? How else would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the [Glue Dynamic Dataframe supports a join operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-join), though it's limited to inner joins. The Spark dataframe has a [robust join method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) that supports inner, outer, and cross joins. So you should be able to load all three S3 locations into (dynamic) dataframes and join them to get a single result set that you can transform and write out.

Comment: is there a blog post or a tutorial you can point me to? thanks!

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-join-multiple-dataframes/ looks decent and includes an example of a three-dataframe join towards the end. If you're not familiar with SQL joins, you may want to do some practice with those just so you're familiar with the concepts.